# Transistor for 38kHz IR pulse amplification

Tags: transistors, timer, 555, infrared

I am trying to build a timer circuit in which I will send a modulated 38kHz (almost) signal to an IR Receiver (TSOP38238 in Arduino Nano) and I want to amplify the square wave to the IR Led to maximize the range of my circuit.

I use 2 555 NE555P timers in order to achieve this. The first timer produces a 1kHz, 50.25% duty pulse, and its output is connected to the reset pin of the 2nd 555 timer which generates a 38kHz (almost) square wave (50.25% duty with R1 = 1K and R2 = 100K and C = 0.2nF). The point of the first 555 timers with the modulation pulse is because in the future I want to use more of these "transmitters" with different modulations in order to measure the length of the pulse and understand which transmitter sent the pulse.

My question is that if I want to use a BJT in the output pin of the 2nd timer to drive my IR LED what should I be careful about in order to amplify my pulse without any disturbances? Does all BJTs do for this job or there are some characteristics that I should watch out?

Comment: Why not follow the Rx datasheet?  (IR diode TSAL6200, If = 0.4A, 30 pulses, f = fo , t = 10 cycles minimum)  You need to regulate the current limit accurately for a given pulse width either by accurate V and R series or current sense and regulate

Comment: My source is at 5V. I don't understand exactly what you mean. You say that if I want to send 38pulses for this certain amount of time I need to draw a specified amount of current or this value is the max current that I can draw?

Comment: That is peak current for a short burst. How much do you know about regulating  high current diodes to prevent burnout

Comment: I don't know a lot but I think that I could use a Schottky diode here to prevent some bursts and because of the fact that they can handle high frequencies without to interfere the signal. My point is that if there is an easy way to amplify my square wave then I will do it but If I need to go deep into electronics and learn some things first in order to amplify my signal I would need some guidance.

Comment: You need to understand, IR diode VI curve has about 1 ohm ESR at 400mA peak at 1.65V for TSAL6200 which means if only 1.5V you drop -150mV* 1 ohm = 400mA -150mA = 250mA which reduces range.

Comment: So even if I use a BJT transistor I would not amplify my signal? I can't really understand what you say and I don't really understand why should I be so much precise with my calculations. If I don't have the range I want couldn't I just measure the current and drop the R until I reach my wanted range?

Comment: You can pulse 2 IR diodes in series from 3.3V with 400mA only using a MOSFET with RdsOn << 100mohm  or from 3V with less current and less range.  your choice . A transistor will have too much voltage drop ( unless you know what you are doing)